# How to pin or lock flutter app to screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app for transport government regulatory purposes where in some cases users would be required to hand their device to officers to check for compliance. I would like to be able to allow users to lock the app to a certain compliance section of the app so that there is no access to other areas of the app. Minimizing and closing the app from the device buttons would also need to be disabled, or require device reauthentication again to prevent access to personal files etc. The functionality I am looking for would be similar to "pinning" an app to the screen in android.

Is anyone aware of any packages or paths I could take to achieve this functionality?

Thanks